# how to change uppercase to lowercase with regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

It could be any string, it should match only the UPPERCASE part and change to lowercase, for example:

`"It's around August AND THEN I get an email"`

become

`"It's around August and then I get an email"`

as you can see the word `It's`, `August` and `I` should be ignored

Comment: "UPPERCASE part" ?? which are the delimiters?

Comment: Do you have any parameters that define what should be ignored/not ignored?

Comment: Why should `It's August I` be ignored? Is there any hidden requirements there? Like, the first word of the sentence should be preserved, the month names,....

Comment: What if your input is `It's HTML`?

Comment: Why use RegEx for this? its as simple as `value.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [`/\b[A-Z]{2,}\b/g`](https://regex101.com/r/qY5jO7/2) to match all-caps words and then [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback that lowercases matches.

```js
var string = "It's around August AND THEN I get an email",
  regex = /\b[A-Z]{2,}\b/g;

var modified = string.replace(regex, function(match) {
  return match.toLowerCase();
});

console.log(modified);
// It's around August and then I get an email
```

Also, feel free to use a more complicated expression. This one will look for capitalized words with 1+ length with "I" as the exception (I also made one that looked at the first word of a sentence different, but that was more complicated and requires updated logic in the callback function since you still want the first letter capitalized):

```
\b(?!I\b)[A-Z]+\b
```

Comment: Any chance the replacement from upper-case to lower-case can be done by the regex engine itself?

Answer (score 5):

A solution without regex:

```js
function isUpperCase(str) {
        return str === str.toUpperCase();
    }

var str = "It's around August AND THEN I get an email";
var matched = str.split(' ').map(function(val){
  if (isUpperCase(val) && val.length>1) {
    return val.toLowerCase();
    }
  return val;        
});

console.log(matched.join(' '));
```

Comment: Cool, this solution is useful for another problem I had, thanks!